# Prevent FormTokenField component to accept random entries

Tags: block-editor

[FormTokenField](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/form-token-field/) component has [suggestions property](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/form-token-field/#properties) which provides a list of suggestions when user start typing.

But, FormTokenField also accepts any value, if separated by comma, even if it is not defined in the suggestions property. Just like you can add anything to Post Categories and Post Tags field.

Is there a way to prevent this? I would like to limit users to be able to only add items from suggestions.

Or, if this is not possible with the FormTokenField, is there any other component that could do this - allow users to select multiple items from predefined lists of options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a recent project I handled this by just filtering out invalid values in the `onChange` callback:

```
export default () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
    const suggestions = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'];

    const onChange = (tokens) => {
        const value = tokens.filter((t) => suggestions.includes(t));

        setValue(value);
    };

    return <FormTokenField onChange={onChange} suggestions={suggestions} value={value} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The validation feature is currently flagged as "experimental," which means that it may change at any point without warning and may require the Gutenberg plugin to use. If you do choose to use it, you'll want to keep an eye out for updates on the status of the interface.

It's exposed through the `__experimentalValidateInput` prop which is passed a callback. The callback receives a newly input value as an argument, and may return a truthy value to accept the input or a falsey value to deny it. You might use it as such:

```js
import { FormTokenField } from '@wordpress/components'
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

// A multiple Post-Type selection control implemented on top of FormTokenField.
const PostTypesControl = ( props ) => {
  const { value = [], onChange } = props;

  const types = useSelect(
    ( select ) =>  ( select( 'core' ).getPostTypes() ?? [] ).map( ( { slug, name } ) => ( { value: slug, title: name } ) ),
    []
  );

  const tokenIsValid = ( title ) => types.some( type => type.title === title );
  const titleToValue = ( title ) => title ? types.find( type => type.title === title )?.value || '' : '';

  return (
    <FormTokenField
      value={ value }
      onChange={ onChange }
      suggestions={ types.map( type => type.title ) }
      saveTransform={ titleToValue }
      __experimentalValidateInput={ tokenIsValid }
    />
  );
};
```

> is there any other component that could do this - allow users to select multiple items from predefined lists of options?

[`<SelectControl>`](https://wordpress.github.io/gutenberg/?path=/story/components-selectcontrol--default) with `multiple` enabled comes to mind, but there may be others.